# vba double error inputbox string

Tags: vba, sum, double, string-concatenation

I am using VBA with activex control in excel
I have this code to calculate the average of two values

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim a, b, average As Double
a = InputBox("insert number a")
b = InputBox("insert number b")
average = (a + b) / 2
MsgBox (average)
End Sub
```

It returns a wrong value since + is considered as concatenation of strings instead of the sum of two double.
For example if I put a=4 and b=5 the result is 22.5 (45/2).

The problem is solved if the variable declaration is modified as follow, just
declaring the variables one by one

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim a  As Double
Dim b As Double
Dim average As Double
a = InputBox("insert number a")
b = InputBox("insert number b")
average = (a + b) / 2
MsgBox (average)
End Sub
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

`InputBox` returns as string, and because you Dimmed things like this

```
Dim a, b, average As Double
```

`a` and `b` are `Variants`, not `Double`

So they get converted to `String` by the `InputBox`.

Change the average calculation to this:

```
average = (val(a) + val(b)) / 2
```

That will convert the strings to numbers and then add them.

Note: When using an `InputBox` and you expect numbers, you will want to have some checks in their too in case the person enters something that is not numeric, because `Val` will convert non-numeric text to `0`

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, if you "Dim" more than one variable in a line you must explicitly give the type for each variable. If you don't, the variables get the type "Variant".

So in this line:

```
Dim a, b, average As Double
```

`a` and `b` are of type Variant, only `average` is of type Double. (Variant means VBA will guess which data type to use.) But

```
Dim a as Double, b As Double, average As Double
```

will work as you wish, same as your second code sample. It's just the way VBA was designed, some twenty plus years ago...